# Replacing TbButton with CHtml::link in Yii

Tags: yii

My scenario is whenever client clicks on the link, twitter bootstrap modal will be displayed. So far, I modified widget CJuiDialog to become Bootstrap widget

```
<?php
/** Start Widget **/
    //$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
    //    'id'=>'mydialog',
    //    'options'=>array(
    //        'title'=>'Dialog box',
    //        'autoOpen'=>false,
    //  ),
    //));
    $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbModal', array('id'=>'myModal')); 
    //echo 'dialog content here';
?>
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
<h4>Modal Header Part</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal-body"><p>One Fine Body...</p></div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'type'=>'primary',
        'label'=>'Save changes',
        'url'=>'#',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
     )); ?>
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'label'=>'Close',
        'url'=>'#',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('data-dismiss'=>'modal'),
    )); ?>
</div>
<?php
    //$this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
    $this->endWidget();
    /** End Widget **/
?>
<?php echo CHtml::link('Open Dialog', '#', array('onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;',));?>
```

But unfortunately it did not work, Does anyone know how to link using CHtml::link like in CJuiDialog? 
Instead of having bootstrap widget as below which is working fine

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label'=>'Open Dialog',
    'type'=>'primary',
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'data-toggle'=>'modal',
        'data-target'=>'#myModal',
    ),
 )); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

After the [official manual](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals), you need to set the link attributes href="#[modelID]" and data-toggle="modal":

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
```

To generate such a link with Yii, use this code:

```
<?php
echo CHtml::link(
    'Open Dialog',
    '#myModal',
    array('data-toggle' => 'modal')
);
```

Comment: thanks fabian, i've never open my stackoverflow for ages, thanks for reply